# AJAX returning error Unexpected End of JSON Input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My AJAX is returning the following error.

```
parsererror
(index):75 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Nb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

It is working fine on localhost but not on live server.

This is my AJAX Call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'server.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        request: 'GET_COMPLAINTS'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success == 'true') {
            if (data.complaints != undefined) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.complaints.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == '0') {
                        dir = 'left';
                    } else {
                        dir = 'right';
                    }
                    $('.messages').append('<li class="message ' + dir + ' appeared"><div class="avatar"></div><div class="text_wrapper"><div class="text">' + data.complaints[i] + '</div></div></li>');
                }
            }
            $(".messages").animate({scrollTop: $('.messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 5000);
        } else {
        }
    },
    error: function (a,b,c) {
        //swal("Oops...", a.responseText, "error");
        console.log(a);console.log(b);console.log(c);
    }
});
```

And in the server.php I am doing this.

```
function getComplaints() {
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: That server PHP will do absolutely nothing.  Is there more code?

Comment: No I am just posting this data to my server.php. But I don't go inside success function, but error function. It is working absolutely fine on localhost. But not on live.

Comment: Look at the network tab in your browser's dev tools. What does the response contain?

Comment: Its blank @JasonP

Comment: Well a blank string isn't valid json, hence the error you're getting. The next step would be to debug why you aren't getting any content in the response. You haven't included enough php to determine what the problem is.

Comment: My $_POST is not working in server.php. Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe you have some extra php code running on your localhost (a function or a plugin) that handles the $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error. Seems that there was .htaccess on my live and it was blocking all $_POST Requests, therefore I used $_GET.